# C# How to loop Excel named range with foreach method

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I need to loop some Excel data but it will be 1million data in each files.

I tried to used "for" and "Parallel.For" for looping but it's too slow, hence I would like to try to use foreach but I don't know how to make it. The Parallel.For code are in below:

```
Parallel.For(2, lastUsedRow, i =>
       {
           int AddValue = DValue + 1;
           DValue = AddValue;
           currentsheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = AddValue + "/" + lastUsedRow;
           if (currentsheet.Cells[i, 3].Value != "")
           {
               currentsheet.Cells[i, 3].Value = Regex.Replace(currentsheet.Cells[i, 3].Text, "[ \\[ \\] \\^ \\-_*×――(^)（^）$%~!@#$…&%￥—+=<>《》!！??？:：•`·、。，；,.;\"‘’“”-]", "");
               currentsheet.Cells[i, 3].Value = currentsheet.Cells[i, 3].Text.ToUpper();
               currentsheet.Cells[i, 3].Value = currentsheet.Cells[i, 3].Text.Replace(" ", "");
           }
           else
           {
               currentsheet.Cells[i, 3].Value = "";
           }
           string COLVALUE = currentsheet.Cells[i, 3].Text;
           if (Regex.Matches(COLVALUE, "[a-zA-Z]").Count != 0 & COLVALUE.Length != 12)
           {
               currentsheet.Cells[i, 3].Value = "";
               currentsheet.Cells[i, 4].Value = COLVALUE;
           }
       });
```

Did every friends here know how to make a foreach loop in a range of row or in a named range ? Many thanks.

Comment: I believe if you're manually looping through *each* value within the Excel file with *millions* of records, it's going to take a long time no matter what.

Comment: @Symon Hi, did any suggestion that can be make it faster ?

Comment: Or did any range.replace method with Regex condition ?

Comment: the else statement "currentsheet.Cells[i, 3].Value = "";" is useless. Also in the last loop you can check first the colvalue.Length.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion to try here. You can break up the list into sub-ranges, say 10k each, and read those ranges into arrays of C# memory and perform the updates on the array directly in C# instead of individual rows. Then you paste the entire array back into Excel as a single range. Pasting an entire range is a single operation and is much faster than iterating over rows 1 at a time.

You can try doing this one range at a time, or in parallel and experimenting with different size ranges.

I know working with in-memory arrays in VBA is MUCH faster than accessing the worksheet/rows. I assume it's the same with C#, and would speculate that the performance gain is even greater since C# is Interop when VBA isn't.